# PyQt System tray and fullscreen

Tags: python, qt, pyqt4, system-tray

I've build and application that gets some messages via ZeroMQ and show them in the System Tray using PyQt. The problem is that if there is an application running in fullscreen it still shows the message, being a pain for the user for obvious reason. My questions are:

Is there any way to know if there is an application in fullscreen so I can tell my application to not show the message?

Is there any option that I haven't see so far to tell the application to not show the message if something is in fullscreen?

Is there anyway to tell the system to not show a message at all if there is something in fullscreen?

In summary, can I do anything with this? or just make a variable in my application that the user can modify and check it if he doesn't want to see the messages.

Comment: Can you show us a code snippet, of how you show the message in the system tray? Then we can toy with it ourselves trying to find a solution.

Allowing your users to turn off those messages if they don't want to see them may be a good idea regardless of this issue ;-)